# lodash; replace and merge two arrays of strings

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, lodash

Is there any function in [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs) to merge two arrays something like;

```
var arr_1 = ['1', '0', '1'], arr_2 = ['0', '1', '1'];
```

Result should return:

```
console.log(new_arr); // ['0', '0', '1']
```

**Update**

Each array has 3 elements (strings). Whenever `'0'` is found in any of the two arrays, it must remain in the result.

Comment: And how would you get that result, the first number is from the second array, then the second number is from the first array etc. is there a system here? Should it select the lowest number or what ?

Comment: How is the result supposed to be determined? If both at an index are `'1'` then `'1'` else `'0'`?

Comment: `var arr_3 = arr_1.map(function(x, i) { return Math.min(x, arr_2[i]) });`

Comment: Why don't you have a look at the documentation you linked to?

Comment: @FelixKling I did but couldn't find anything like what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this :

ES5:

```
_.map(_.zip(arr_1,arr_2), function(values) { 
      return values[0] <= values[1] ? values[0] : values[1]; 
})
```

ES6: ( way nicer )

```
_.zip(arr_1,arr_2).map( v => v[0] <= v[1] ? v[0] : v[1] );
```

It isn't just one method, but it uses [lodash zip](https://lodash.com/docs#zip).

Answer (score 0):

The following should get you what you need. It uses [flatten()](https://lodash.com/docs#flatten) to create one array, and from there, [reduce()](https://lodash.com/docs#reduce) to create a new array with '0' duplicates allowed, and all other duplicates removed.

```
_([arr_1, arr_2])
    .flatten()
    .reduce(function(result, item) {
        if (item === '0' || !_.includes(result, item)) { 
            result.push(item);
        }
        return result; 
    }, []);
```